# create-react-app is ignoring yarn's registry config value

Tags: create-react-app, yarnpkg

I am not sure if this is a problem with `create-react-app` or `yarn`.

I am trying to use `create-react-app`. It seems to use `yarn` under the hood to fetch dependencies, but `yarn` is ignoring its own registry config setting and tries to download packages directly from https://registry.yarnpkg.com/.

This is the output when I try to use `create-react-app`. You can see at the end that `yarn` ignores the registry config setting:

```
$ npx create-react-app@2.1.2 my-app --verbose --registry "http://myownregistry:1234/"
npm info it worked if it ends with ok
npm info using npm@6.4.1
npm info using node@v10.13.0
npm timing npm Completed in 153ms
npm info ok
npx: installed 63 in 72.714s

Creating a new React app in C:\work\my-app.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

yarn add v1.13.0
verbose 0.399 Checking for configuration file "C:\\work\\my-app\\.npmrc".
verbose 0.4 Checking for configuration file "C:\\Users\\jbloggs\\.npmrc".
verbose 0.4 Found configuration file "C:\\Users\\jbloggs\\.npmrc".
verbose 0.401 Checking for configuration file "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\etc\\npmrc".
verbose 0.401 Checking for configuration file "C:\\work\\my-app\\.npmrc".
verbose 0.402 Checking for configuration file "C:\\work\\.npmrc".
verbose 0.406 Checking for configuration file "C:\\work\\my-app\\.yarnrc".
verbose 0.406 Checking for configuration file "C:\\Users\\jbloggs\\.yarnrc".
verbose 0.406 Found configuration file "C:\\Users\\jbloggs\\.yarnrc".
verbose 0.407 Checking for configuration file "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\etc\\yarnrc".
verbose 0.407 Checking for configuration file "C:\\work\\my-app\\.yarnrc".
verbose 0.407 Checking for configuration file "C:\\work\\.yarnrc".
verbose 0.417 current time: 2019-01-21T16:43:06.912Z
[1/4] Resolving packages...
verbose 0.637 Performing "GET" request to "http://myownregistry:1234/react".
verbose 2.827 Request "http://myownregistry:1234/react" finished with status code 200.
verbose 2.837 Performing "GET" request to "http://myownregistry:1234/loose-envify".
verbose 2.839 Performing "GET" request to "http://myownregistry:1234/scheduler".

[... lots of similar lines removed lines removed ...]

verbose 23.218 Request "http://myownregistry:1234/string_decoder" finished with status code 200.
[2/4] Fetching packages...
verbose 23.473 Performing "GET" request to "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/object-assign/-/object-assign-4.1.1.tgz".
verbose 23.483 Performing "GET" request to "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/prop-types/-/prop-types-15.6.2.tgz".
verbose 23.486 Performing "GET" request to "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/loose-envify/-/loose-envify-1.4.0.tgz".
verbose 23.492 Performing "GET" request to "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/js-tokens/-/js-tokens-4.0.0.tgz".
verbose 23.514 Performing "GET" request to "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/babel-core/-/babel-core-7.0.0-bridge.0.tgz".
verbose 23.518 Performing "GET" request to "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@babel/core/-/core-7.1.6.tgz".
verbose 23.52 Performing "GET" request to "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/@svgr/webpack/-/webpack-2.4.1.tgz".
verbose 23.531 Performing "GET" request to "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/babel-eslint/-/babel-eslint-9.0.0.tgz".
Missing dependencies in package.json
```

However, if I use Yarn on its own, it will use the registry config value.

```
$ yarn add object-assign@4.1.1 --verbose
yarn add v1.13.0
verbose 0.375 Checking for configuration file "C:\\work\\.npmrc".
verbose 0.376 Checking for configuration file "C:\\Users\\jbloggs\\.npmrc".
verbose 0.376 Found configuration file "C:\\Users\\jbloggs\\.npmrc".
verbose 0.378 Checking for configuration file "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\etc\\npmrc".
verbose 0.379 Checking for configuration file "C:\\work\\.npmrc".
verbose 0.383 Checking for configuration file "C:\\work\\.yarnrc".
verbose 0.383 Checking for configuration file "C:\\Users\\jbloggs\\.yarnrc".
verbose 0.383 Found configuration file "C:\\Users\\jbloggs\\.yarnrc".
verbose 0.384 Checking for configuration file "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\etc\\yarnrc".
verbose 0.384 Checking for configuration file "C:\\work\\.yarnrc".
verbose 0.39 current time: 2019-01-21T16:48:15.659Z
info No lockfile found.
[1/4] Resolving packages...
verbose 0.488 Performing "GET" request to "http://myownregistry:1234/object-assign".
verbose 3.892 Request "http://myownregistry:1234/object-assign" finished with status code 200.
[2/4] Fetching packages...
verbose 3.932 Performing "GET" request to "http://myownregistry:1234/object-assign/-/object-assign-4.1.1.tgz".
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
verbose 4.143 Creating directory "C:\\work\\node_modules\\object-assign".
verbose 4.146 Copying "C:\\Users\\jbloggs\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Cache\\v4\\npm-object-assign-4.1.1-2109adc7965887cfc05cbbd442cac8bfbb360863\\node_modules\\object-assign\\index.js" to "C:\\work\\node_modules\\object-assign\\index.js".
verbose 4.147 Copying "C:\\Users\\jbloggs\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Cache\\v4\\npm-object-assign-4.1.1-2109adc7965887cfc05cbbd442cac8bfbb360863\\node_modules\\object-assign\\license" to "C:\\work\\node_modules\\object-assign\\license".
verbose 4.147 Copying "C:\\Users\\jbloggs\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Cache\\v4\\npm-object-assign-4.1.1-2109adc7965887cfc05cbbd442cac8bfbb360863\\node_modules\\object-assign\\package.json" to "C:\\work\\node_modules\\object-assign\\package.json".
verbose 4.147 Copying "C:\\Users\\jbloggs\\AppData\\Local\\Yarn\\Cache\\v4\\npm-object-assign-4.1.1-2109adc7965887cfc05cbbd442cac8bfbb360863\\node_modules\\object-assign\\readme.md" to "C:\\work\\node_modules\\object-assign\\readme.md".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 1 new dependency.
info Direct dependencies
+- object-assign@4.1.1
info All dependencies
+- object-assign@4.1.1
Done in 3.86s.
```

What can I do to get `create-react-app` to invoke `yarn` in a way that `yarn` uses the registry config value?

Answer (score 2):

I got same issue today and found the root cause, there is a [piece of code](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/create-react-app/createReactApp.js#L282) checking for custom registry in yarn config. If not found then cached `yarn.lock` file (with links to default registry inside) is copied to target folder before install:

```
if (yarnUsesDefaultRegistry) {
  fs.copySync(
    require.resolve('./yarn.lock.cached'),
    path.join(root, 'yarn.lock')
  );
}
```

When you run the same install command from command line, then no conflict with generated lock file and all installs smoothly using your `.npmrc`. It was quite tricky to catch this as `create-react-app` clears lock file on failed install :).
I would consider this as `create-react-app` issue. Simple workaround is to set custom registry to yarn explicitly:

```
yarn config set registry http://myownregistry:1234 --global
```

Next create-react-app run will pick up this property and skip copying of cached lock file.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, initial `yarn` installation of create-react-app doesn't accept/honor custom registry settings([Source code](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/create-react-app/createReactApp.js#L304)). But it does honor `--verbose` option([Source code](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/create-react-app/createReactApp.js#L344)).

You can create issue in official repo for custom registry support. There are some issues around this already(like [this one](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5991)). but, looks like this is a good to have feature.